# React - restrict to numeric/alphanumeric/hexadecimal symbols in text field with max length

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm working on `React.js` project.
I wanna create 3 Text Fields where:

**1st** Text Field - I want to insert only hexadecimal values.
It should accept the numbers from 0-9 & letters from A-F & colon.
It should accept only 23 chars(numbers, letters from A-F & colon).

**2nd** Text Field- It should only Hexadecimal values.

**3rd** Text Field- It should accept only Alpha Numeric values (only Numbers &
letters).

**4th** Text Field- Only Letters.

Note: Special Characters should not be accepted.

Please help me out to solve this.

Sample Code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);this.state = {showModal: true};
  this.modalFooter = this.modalFooter.bind(this);
  this.modalBody = this.modalBody.bind(this); this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);     
};

modalFooter() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BButton name="Cancel" onClickHandler={() => { this.setState({ showModal: false }) }} />
    </div>);
}

modalBody() {
  return (
    <div>
      <br className="Class">
        <br> Hex Value: <input type="text" className="Class" formnovalidate="return isNumber(event)"
          maxLength="23" placeholder="" /></br>
        <br> Addr:  <input type="text" className="Class" maxLength="6" name=""
          placeholder="" /></br><br> Name: <input type="text" className="Class" id="Number"
            maxLength="64"
            name="" placeholder="" /></br>
      </br>
    </div>
  );
}

updateState(e) {
  this.setState({data: e.target.value});
}

render() {
  let body = this.modalBody();
  let footer = this.modalFooter();
  let modal = <BModal header="Add Message"
    body={body}
    footer={footer} />
  return (
    <div className="page-title">
      <center>
        <h3> Sample Program </h3>
      </center>
      <hr className="horizontal-line"></hr>

      <div>  <font color="grey"><input type="text" value={this.state.data}
        onClick={() => { this.setState({ showModal: true }) }} /></font>
        {this.state.showModal ? modal : ""}
      </div>
    </div>);

}
```

Comment: Provide some code... No one will give you solution without seeing effort from you.

Comment: Give me some ideas guys....Actually I'm new to React.Js.

Answer (score 20):

I suggest you to use React `onKeyPress` event with regexp verifications (see example below and the jsbin link)

```
var Form = React.createClass({

  firstMethod(e) {
    const re = /[0-9A-F:]+/g;
    if (!re.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },

  secondMethod(e) {
    const re = /[0-9A-F]+/g;
    if (!re.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },

  thirdMethod(e) {
    const re = /[0-9a-fA-F]+/g;
    if (!re.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },

  fourthMethod(e) {
    const re = /[a-fA-F]+/g;
    if (!re.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input ref="first" onKeyPress={(e) => this.firstMethod(e)} />
        <input ref="second" onKeyPress={(e) => this.secondMethod(e)} />
        <input ref="third" onKeyPress={(e) => this.thirdMethod(e)} />
        <input ref="fourth" onKeyPress={(e) => this.fourthMethod(e)} />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

http://jsbin.com/juyakaqawe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. But the thing is, I have to create it in a separate component and I have to call it from there.

Comment: This approach worked just fine for me! You just pick one of the fuctions above, add to the component and apply the onKeyPress method to the input element like in the exemple.

Comment: Does not work for pasted input

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's not complicated at all. You only need to take care of extracting allowed characters from text input, limit its length, ... 
To be honest, this is not related to React in any way - it's pure Javascript.

Let's begin with simple function which extracts substring from string by pattern

```
const extract = (str, pattern) => (str.match(pattern) || []).pop() || '';
// Usage
extract("01az", "[0-9a-fA-F]+") // "01a"
```

Then, wrap this function into functions which solve pattern problems for 1, 2, 3 and 4

```
const extractHexadecimalWithColon = (str) => extract(str, "[0-9a-fA-F:]+");

const extractHexadecimal = (str) => extract(str, "[0-9a-fA-F]+");

const extractAlphanum = (str) => extract(str, "[0-9a-zA-Z]+");

const extractAlpha = (str) => extract(str, "[a-zA-Z]+");
```

It super easy to limit length of string

```
const limitLength = (str, length) => str.substring(0, length);
```

Then, create your text inputs components, listen for changes and update state as required.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {};
  },

  setA(e) {
    this.setState({
      a: limitLength(extractHexadecimalWithColon(e.target.value), 23),
    });
  },

  setB(e) {
    this.setState({
      b: extractHexadecimal(e.target.value),
    });
  },

  setC(e) {
    this.setState({
      c: extractAlphanum(e.target.value),
    });
  },

  setD(e) {
    this.setState({
      d: extractAlpha(e.target.value),
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Hexadecimal, max 23 chars, colon allowed<br/>
          <textarea value={this.state.a} onChange={this.setA} />
        </div>

        <div>
          Hexadecimal only, no length restriction<br/>
          <textarea value={this.state.b} onChange={this.setB} />
        </div>

        <div>
          Alphanumeric<br/>
          <textarea value={this.state.c} onChange={this.setC} />
        </div>

        <div>
          Letters only<br/>
          <textarea value={this.state.d} onChange={this.setD} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Full working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36536/

Original solution split into separate components https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36654/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. But the thing is, I have to create it in a separate component and I have to call it from there.

Comment: What's the problem with passing values and onChange callbacks to that component?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working demo of a *complete* highly-generic `Input` component which has its smarts by utilizing the [HTML5 pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute and blocking undesired content according to the *regular expression* defined in the `pattern` prop:

```js
const Input = (props) => {
  const onKeyPress = e => {
    // normalize the pattern as a Regular expression
    const pattern = props.pattern instanceof RegExp ? props.pattern : new RegExp(props.pattern)
    
    // if the currently typed character is not in the regular expression, do not allow it (to be rendered)
    // if the length of the input will exceed, do not allow
    if( !pattern.test(e.key) || e.target.value.length + 1 > (props.max||Infinity))
      e.preventDefault()

    // if also has "onKeyPress" prop, fire it now
    props.onKeyPress && props.onKeyPress(e) 
  }
  
  // prevent invalid content pasting
  const onPaste = e => {
    // get the pattern with midifications for testig a whole string rather than a single character
    const pattern = props.pattern instanceof RegExp ? props.pattern : new RegExp(`^${props.pattern}+$`)
    
    // get pasted content as string
    const paste = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text')
    
    // vaildate
    if( !pattern.test(paste) || paste.length > (props.max||Infinity))
      e.preventDefault()
      
    // if also has "onPaste" prop, fire it now
    props.onPaste && props.onPaste(e) 
  }
    
  return <input {...props} onKeyPress={onKeyPress} onPaste={onPaste} />
}


ReactDOM.render((
<form>
  <Input pattern="[0-9a-fA-F:]" max={6} placeholder="Only HEXA & colon, up to 6 chars"/>
  <Input pattern="[0-9a-fA-F]" placeholder="Only HEXA"/>
  <Input pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z]" placeholder="Only Alphanumeric"/>
  <Input pattern="[a-zA-Z]" placeholder="Only (Latin) Letters"/>
  <Input placeholder="Everything allowed"/>
</form>)
, root)
```

```css
input{
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```